# Laravel undefined variable inside a function

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I get my `$id` from the url, but I couldn't find a way to use it in a function. How can I pass $id to the query function?

I tried global $id but I still can't get a value, just empty page.

My controller.

```
class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function bookIndex($id, $slug)
    {
     // echo $id works without a problem
     $findcover = Thing::with(array('cover' => function($query) {
                $query->where('imageable_type', 'App\Models\Thing')
                  ->where('imageable_id', $id);
            }))->find($id);

            $maincover = $findcover->cover;
}
```

Error:

```
ErrorException in BookController.php line 49:
Undefined variable: id
```

Line 49

```
->where('imageable_id', $id);
```

Comment: `function($query) use $id`?

Comment: Yes, I need to use that $id inside my function.

Comment: What i mean is insert that in your query

Comment: I can't pass more than one parameter into that function, it accepts only one parameter.

Comment: Change your query to this `Thing::with('cover' => function($query) use $id { });`'

Comment: Ah, I got it now. Thank you! You can add this as an answer if you want, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
class BookController extends Controller
{
   public function bookIndex($id, $slug) {
   // echo $id works without a problem

   $findcover = Thing::with(array('cover' => function($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('imageable_type', 'App\Models\Thing')
              ->where('imageable_id', $id);
        }))->find($id);

        $maincover = $findcover->cover;
   }
```

Add the reserve word **use** to insert your `$id` along your query.

Comment: This was very close for me. I just needed to put the `$id` variable in parenthesis `use ($id)`.

Comment: `$id` should be in parenthesis